# Highcharts update xAxis category when calling series.setData

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Right now I have a column chart that takes an array as data like `[ ['name1', 23], ['name2', 46] ]`. This works fine and the xAxis renders properly as long as you set `xAxis: { type: 'category' }`.

But when I run `chart.series.setData()` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) to change the dataset that I use, it doesn't take in the new xAxis values. It sets the xAxis from 0-x depending on how large the dataset is. I want it to be just like the first example, name1, name2 etc.

You can see the problem in the fiddle when you click the "button" button. The axis doesn't change in this case even though the new dataset gets applied.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkarkar/d555ak3v/

How do I use setData and also update the xAxis category names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In highcharts there is method [`update`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update)

Try this

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var chartTest = $('#graph3').highcharts();
    chartTest.series[0].update({data: data2});
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/d555ak3v/3/)

or

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var chartTest = $('#graph3').highcharts();

    chartTest.series[0].setData(data2, false, true, false);
    chartTest.redraw()     
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/d555ak3v/4/)